# Access problem with service account in gcloud from github actions

Tags: docker, gcloud, github-actions

I'm quite new to github actions and gcloud. I have trouble to get my github-CI/CD-Pipeline running because I can't push any docker image to the google Cloud Registry due to access restrictions.

What have I done so far:

- I have a Quarkus app hosted on github
- I used github actions to build the Maven project and the docker image
- I created a project in google Cloud and added a service account which I use for the github action. The login seems to work:

```
Run google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
/usr/bin/tar xz --warning=no-unknown-keyword -C /home/runner/work/_temp/ac85f67a-89fa-4eb4-8d30-3f6379124ec2 -f /home/runner/work/_temp/de491940-a4b1-4a15-bf0a-95d563e68362
/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/342.0.0/x64/bin/gcloud --quiet config set project ***
Updated property [core/project].
Successfully set default project
/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/342.0.0/x64/bin/gcloud --quiet auth activate-service-account github-actions@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file -
Activated service account credentials for: [github-actions@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

- If I now try to push the docker image I get the following (expected) error message:

```
Run docker push "$GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG"
The push refers to repository [eu.gcr.io/***/***]
715ac1ae8693: Preparing
435cfe5f5775: Preparing
313d03d71d4d: Preparing
c5c8d86ccee1: Preparing
1b0f2238925b: Preparing
144a43b910e8: Preparing
4a2bc86056a8: Preparing
144a43b910e8: Waiting
4a2bc86056a8: Waiting
denied: Token exchange failed for project '***'. Caller does not have permission 'storage.buckets.get'. To configure permissions, follow instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

- Next, I opened the Google Cloud Console and created a custom role (IAM & Admin -> Roles -> Create Role) which has the necessary permissions.
- Then, I had trouble to assign my new custom role to the service account (IAM & Admin -> Service Accounts -> Manage Access -> Add member). I used the email address of the service account as "New members", but I could not choose the custom role I just created. **What am I missing here?**
- I read somewhere that I can also add service accounts as member (IAM & Admin -> IAM -> Add). Again I used the email address of the service account as "New Members". This time I could choose my custom role. **What's the difference to the first approach?**
- Anyways, if a I try to run the github action again, now I get the following error:

```
Run docker push "$GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG"
The push refers to repository [eu.gcr.io/***/***]
c4f14c9d3b6e: Preparing
fe78d438e8e2: Preparing
843fcae4a8f4: Preparing
dcf8cc80cedb: Preparing
45e8815b101d: Preparing
144a43b910e8: Preparing
4a2bc86056a8: Preparing
144a43b910e8: Waiting
4a2bc86056a8: Waiting
denied: Access denied.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The error message is different, so I guess the permission for the service account somehow worked, but still I can't succeed. **Which steps did I miss?**

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug this is to create a key for the service account on your local host, configure your script|`gcloud` to use the service account as its credentials and then try the push manually.

One immediate problem may be that you're not authenticating against Google Container Registry (GCR). GCR implements Docker's registry API and you'll need to use one of the mechanisms to [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) **before** you can interact with the registry.

Notes:

1. I think you don't need to create a custom role. You have 2 options. Either (preferred) create an account specifically for the CI/CD job and grant it the minimum set of roles needed including `storage.buckets.get`. I think you can start with `roles/storage.admin` ([link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)) and perhaps refine later.
2. You can grant roles e.g. `roles/storage.admin` to a Project in which case the permission applies to all Cloud Storage resources or to a specific Bucket in which case the permission applies only to the bucket and its objects.
3. Service Accounts have a dual role in GCP. As an identity and as a resource (that can be used by other identities). It can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughts, I'll try that and report on the outcome.